# how to get only contact numbers from the contact list without names?

Tags: android

hi all i used below code it shows all contact details contact numbers and names but i need to get only contact numbers from the the contact list without names how can implement code without using android widget for solve the problem so give solution any one of you

context.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, People.CONTENT_URI));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code...

```
 Uri personUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(People.CONTENT_URI, personId);
Uri phonesUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(personUri, People.Phones.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);
String[] proj = new String[] {Phones._ID, Phones.TYPE, Phones.NUMBER, Phones.LABEL}
Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(phonesUri, proj, null, null, null);
```